# How to set background color inside border in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, border, background-color

**I am trying to set border for which i have made this border.xml file, as i have used background keyword to set background color, but there is no effect of adding background keyword. Can anyone guide me how can i set background color inside border. Here is my border.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">  
<corners android:radius="3dp"/>
<padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#A5A5A5" android:background="#2B1B1B"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: *i have used background keyword*. In which component are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

You just remove **android:background="#2B1B1B"** in stroke and add attribute solid like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">  
<solid android:color="#2B1B1B"
<corners android:radius="3dp"/>
<padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#A5A5A5"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** `android:background="#2B1B1B"` **from 5th line of the code and use this fter third line of your code**

```
<solid android:color="#2B1B1B"/>
```